# "File" object is not accessible in visual studio 2012 (Windows 8)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net

I am Working on Visual Studio 2012 and want to fetch text from file to string so used

```
string line=File.ReadText("Path");
```

But keyword `File` is not default and showing error.
I have Used Assembly Directory `System.IO` but despite that i am unable to key File object nothing other than `filenotfound exception` is accessible.

Comment: did you include `System.IO` in the `using` directives?

Comment: Yes , I had . Inspite that ,Its Not Working

Comment: then please post a complete file that contains the code that is not working.